# How to make an android layout using table for display 4 picture & 10 picture

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-tablelayout

I want to design a interface to display picture

4 rows Table Layout

```
| I  M  A  G  E | | I  M  A  G  E | //<-Two pic @1

| I  M  A  G  E | | I  M  A  G  E | //<-Two pic @2

|IMAGE||IMAGE||IMAGE||IMAGE||IMAGE| //<-Five pic @3

|IMAGE||IMAGE||IMAGE||IMAGE||IMAGE| //<-Five pic @4
```

Without using table layout , any suggestion ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > //it is correct?
<TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"  // it makes become good
        android:src="@drawable/img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />
```

*/i make two pic as one rows here 
*/its good but another table is loss

```
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />   

            <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:src="@drawable/img" />   
</TableRow> //row2


<TableRow> //row3
<ImageView>//row3-img1
<ImageView>//row3-img2
<ImageView>//row3-img3
<ImageView>//row3-img4
<ImageView> //row3-img5
</TableRow> //row3

<TableRow> //row4
<ImageView> //row4-img1
<ImageView>//row4-img2
<ImageView>//row4-img3
<ImageView>//row4-img4
<ImageView>//row4-img5
</TableRow> //row4
</TableLayout>//close table
```

Comment: what you want? be specific

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TableRow>
                <ImageView />   
                <ImageView />   

</TableRow>
<TableRow>
            <ImageView /> 
            <ImageView />   
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>

Comment: @John    I am so sorry asking the question without code... But I am new for using Stack overflow...

Comment: @carinhere Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for posting your base code, but like Hell posted, could you be a little bit more specific about the layout you are trying to make?

Comment: I am trying to make a interface such as table

Comment: the interface i draw in the question

Comment: Two pic view in first and second row , 5 pic view in third and four row

Comment: You want to do this without using table layout. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this helps you.
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView13"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView06"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView05"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView04"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView08"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView09"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView07"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView03"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```